# Get Active Tab in SWT TabFolder

Tags: java, user-interface, swt

I apologize if this question is too basic, but I just can't figure out how to do this. I have a SWT TableFolder with two tabs, and I need to determine which of those two tabs are currently active, as it effects the behavior of another part of the program. Is this possible? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To you mean the *org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TabFolder* (CTabFolder)?

If yes add an eventlistener to your *TabFolder(CTabFolder* object

```
tabFolder.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
  public void widgetSelected(org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionEvent event) {
    tabFolder.getSelection()[0]; // This should be your TabItem/CTabItem
  }
});
```

If you simply have a [*javax.swing.JTabbedPane*](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTabbedPane.html#getSelectedIndex()) then calling

```
yourJTabbedPaneVariableName.getSelectedIndex()
```

gives you the index of the selected Tab

Comment: Thank you very much, that getSelection() is exactly what I needed, I don't know how I missed that.

Comment: javax.swing.JTabbedPane has nothing to do with SWT. Please correct your answer.